# Is it possible to disallow unknown query parameters in an OpenAPI v3 spec?

Tags: openapi

In OpenAPI, you can specify `additionalProperties: false` as [part of an object schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#object) to indicate that extra, unknown properties in a request or response body  will be considered a validation error.

Is there any way to do something similar when [specifying query parameters for an API?](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) I want to indicate that requests including other query parameters beyond those explicitly documented will be considered an error and trigger an HTTP 400 response.

I see that you can mark individual parameters as `required: true`, but I can't find any way to say, "These are the only parameters allowed." Does the OpenAPI 3 spec allow this? If so, how?

Comment: It raises the following question about the OpenAPI3 v3 specification : are  unknown query parameter  forbidden ?  The spec does not say a word on it.  I tend to believe that if you describes explicitly  what is acceptable, implicitly it makes all the unknown things forbidden. But this is certainly opinion base and a clarification in the standard is required (at least, then maybe a yes/no option).
See https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2511
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/568

Comment: I am curious about the same thing, were you able to solve this?

Comment: I threw a 400 error in the application, and documented it in the `description` fields. I couldn't find a way to do this "officially" in OpenAPI v3.