# limit query params in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

is there a way to limit swagger query params?  for example - if somebody submits a `GET` request like:
`/users/bob?product=10`

and accidentally typed in `/users/bob?products=10` - is there a swagger property I can add that will then throw an error?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Is it possible to disallow unknown query parameters in an OpenAPI v3 spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58187233/113116)

Answer (score 1):

Swagger allows you to describe the REST APIs. If `product` is the only query parameter allow, then the server should throw an exception if it finds other query parameters in the request from the client.

In other words, there's no way in Swagger to say parameters with certain names are not allowed as other parameters not documented in Swagger are disallowed by default.

Comment: hi @NickSim - I don't understand the explanation of your answer.  I am asking whether I can restrict the query params.  So that only - for example - `product` is an allowed parameter... everything else will throw an error... in other words, I am wondering if there is functionality in swagger where they will check the query params and see if matches an allowed params list of some sort... throw an error if not, etc....